# Integrationtest .net core with EF core and identity core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, integration-testing

I'm trying to implement automated testing into my .net core 2.2 project. But i can't figure out how to do this with authentication enabled. I read somewhere that for tests you could disable it, but i also want to test access. I use Identity(**not** server) for authentication.

I created in memory databases for each seperate context(default database with products and the identity one). I managed to test the code for grabbing products when there is not [Authorized] attribute and no user tied to it and my testcase works. Now i want to make it a bit more complicated by involving both products, and the user requesting it.

Lets say this is my simplified code:

Controller:

```
[Route("test")]
public class TestController : Controller
{

    private readonly UserManager<User> userManager;

    public TestController(UserManager<User> _usermanager)
    {
        usermanager = _usermanager;
    }

    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    [Authorized(Policy = "Seller")]
    public List<Product> GetAllProductsFromUser()
    {
        User user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
        List<Product> products = db.Products.Where(x => x.userId == user.userId).ToList();
        return products;
    }
}
```

Testcase:

```
 [Fact]
    public async Task Testcase()
    {
        // Arrange
        //Setup a user and get their auth cookie??


        //Act
        //add the auth cookie to the request
        var response = await _client.GetAsync("/test/GetAllProductsFromUser");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        // Assert
        var stringResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var products= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(stringResponse);
        Assert.Equal(3, products.Count);
    }
```

I found out how to populate a database with some info about the products. I haven't found out how i can:

1) create a user from the usermanager;

2) login as that user, retrieve the auth cookie, store it somewhere and use it for my testcases.

3) make the request with that cookie

4) verify the user has the "Seller" claim

Ofcourse none of this should happen in the actual database. I created an inmemory database:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyIdentityContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryIdentityDbForTesting");
            options.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
        });

services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryDbForTesting");
            options.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
        });
```

Comment: you should be setting the current thread principal for the user that you are using for testing, which should get your tests pass as the tests user identity will be set for each test method.

Comment: And how would this work together with an identity login? Do i need to create a User in the "InMemoryIdentityDbForTesting"? because the GenericIdentity will not cover all of the fields I use in there?